# jstree isnt creating the tree from json provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am using jstree to create a treeview of the locations, rooms, and then assets for a company in a PHP app I am writing.

the purpose of this tree is to allow the user to select an asset during a booking wizard which creates a callout job for the particular asset.

I have the following setup on the page:-

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="overflow:auto;" id="assetSelectContainer">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="assetInfo" style="float:right;height:400px;width:45%;">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin:10px;overflow:visible;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:20px;">
          <h4 id="assetname"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Location: <span id="locationname"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Room: <span id="locationroom"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Make: <span id="assetmake"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Model: <span id="assetmodel"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Type: <span id="assettype"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Serial No.: <span id="assetserial"></span></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Asset Tag: <span id="assettag"></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="companyAssetTree" style="float:left;height:400px;width:45%;border:1px solid #ccc;">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery from bookingwizard.js:

```
switch (curStep) {
  case 1:

    $("#roomContainer").hide();
    $('#step3Container').hide();
    var jsondata = $.get("../php/treeviewJSON.php");
    var xdata = ''
    //Load First Dropdown Data
    $('#companyAssetTree').jstree({
      "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "cookie"],
      'core': {
        'check_callback': true,
        'data': {
          url: "../php/treeviewJSON.php"
        }
      }
    });

    break;
```

JSON Returned from server:

```
[{
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Head Office",
    "icon": "fas fa-compass",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Manchester",
    "icon": "fas fa-compass",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Manchester"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "#",
    "text": "Birmingham",
    "icon": "fas fa-compass",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Birmingham"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Server Room",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Server Room"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Office Block 1",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Office Block 1"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Office Block 2",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Office Block 2"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Marketing",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Marketing"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Sales",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Sales"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Customer Service",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Customer Service"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Accounts",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Accounts"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Head Office",
    "text": "Human Resources",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Head Office",
      "room": "Human Resources"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Manchester",
    "text": "Sales",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Manchester",
      "room": "Sales"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Manchester",
    "text": "Server Room",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Manchester",
      "room": "Server Room"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Manchester",
    "text": "Reception",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Manchester",
      "room": "Reception"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Manchester",
    "text": "Office Block 1",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Manchester",
      "room": "Office Block 1"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Birmingham",
    "text": "Sales",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Birmingham",
      "room": "Sales"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Birmingham",
    "text": "Office Block 1",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Birmingham",
      "room": "Office Block 1"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Birmingham",
    "text": "Reception",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Birmingham",
      "room": "Reception"
    }
  }, {
    "id": "string",
    "parent": "Birmingham",
    "text": "Server Room",
    "icon": "fas fa-city",
    "li_attr": {
      "locationname": "",
      "room": "",
      "assetid": 0,
      "assetSerialNo": "",
      "assetTag": ""
    },
    "li_atrr": {
      "locationname": "Birmingham",
      "room": "Server Room"
    }
  }
```

I have followed the documentation from the jstree website and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, I followed their structure for the alternate JSON Format:

```
// Alternative format of the node (id & parent are required)
{
  id: "string" // required
  parent: "string" // required
  text: "string" // node text
  icon: "string" // string for custom
  state: {
    opened: boolean // is the node open
    disabled: boolean // is the node disabled
    selected: boolean // is the node selected
  },
  li_attr: {} // attributes for the generated LI node
  a_attr: {} // attributes for the generated A node
}
```

and the tree isn't even building from the JSON returned from the server.

I really hope someone can point out where I may be going wrong, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I re-approached this issue was to create the HTML for the treeView from serverside and then load that into the element's HTML, after doing that I then called on the treeView

```
$('#companyAssetTree').jstree();
```

As the html structure was all there already the tree created from that, saving me the headache of trying to rectify a massive amount of JSON Data.